# Difference between *x++ and *y += 1

Tags: c++

What is a difference between incrementing `x` and `y`?

```
void inc(unsigned int* x, unsigned int* y) {
    *x++;
    *y += 1;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int x = 0;
    unsigned int y = 0;
    inc(&x, &y);
    printf("x: %u, y: %u", x, y);
    // x: 0, y: 1
}
```

Comment: just wondering why you have parameters as pointers (*) instead of address (&) since you are passing by reference?

Comment: I am not sure. I'd just like to modify `main()` closure variables from `inc` method..

Answer (score 3):

Postfix operators such as postfix `++` take precedence over the unary prefix operators such as `*`. In turn, `*` takes precedence over assignment operators.

Thus, `*x++` means `*(x++)` whereas `*y += 1` means `(*y) += 1`. Equivalently, the latter may be written as `++(*y)`.

Comment: Why do you prefer pre-increment?

Comment: @JohnDoe `+= 1` is equivalent to pre-increment, in that its value is the incremented value. It is not equivalent to post-increment, whose value is the value before incrementation.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
*x++;
```

does not have any effect.

This statement just dereferences the value of the pointer and the pointer itself is increased.

If you want to increment the value pointed to by x you should write

```
++*x;
```

Or if to use the post-increment operator then

```
( *x )++;
```

That is at first you need to dereference the pointer and after that increment the pointed object.

In this statement

```
*y += 1;
```

the value pointed to by y is incremented.

Comment: Thanks, but why not? When I do `x++` it increments by one.

Comment: @JohnDoe exactly you increment x++ which is a pointer. So now it addresses something else. Try (*x)++

Comment: Why do you prefer pre-increment?

Comment: @JohnDoe Because post-increment is error-prone. You need to use parentheses.